# I'm having trouble shuffling a deck of cards in Matlab. Need help to see where I went wrong

Tags: matlab

I currently have the deck of cards coded, but it is unshuffled. This is for programming the card game of War if it helps. I need to shuffle the deck, but whenever I do, it will only shuffle together the card numbers and the suits, not the full card. For example, I have A identified as an ace and the suits come after each number. A normal card would be "AH" (an ace of hearts) or "6D" (a six of diamonds). Instead, it will output "5A" as one of the cards, as in a 5 of aces. I don't know how to fix this, but the code that I currently have is this:

```
card_nums = ('A23456789TJQK')';
card_suits = ('HDSC')';
unshuffled_deck = [repmat(card_nums,4,1),repmat(card_suits,13,1)];
disp(unshuffled_deck)

shuffled_deck = unshuffled_deck(randperm(numel(unshuffled_deck)));
disp(shuffled_deck)
```

I would appreciate any help with this, and thank you very much for your time!

Comment: Took me some minutes to understand why the third row actually works, to have correct code for the more general case (for example a 32 card deck) you could replace it with `unshuffled_deck =allcomb(card_nums,card_suits)` , the code can be found [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/10064-allcomb)

Comment: @Daniel  A **32** card deck?  You running a scam?  :-)

Comment: @Carl Witthoft The [french deck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_playing_cards) is very common in Europe. and used for several games.

Answer (score 5):

You're creating a random permutation of all of the elements from both columns of `unshuffled_deck` combined. Instead you need to create a random permutation of the *rows* of `unshuffled_deck`:

```
shuffled_deck = unshuffled_deck(randperm(size(unshuffled_deck,1)),:);
```

The call to `size` gives you the number of rows in the deck array, then we get a random permutation of the row indices, and copy the row (value, suit) as a single entity.

---

Here's a version using a structure array in response to [@Carl Witthoft's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/884372/carl-witthoft) comment. I was afraid it would add too much complexity to the solution, but it really isn't bad:

```
card_nums = ('A23456789TJQK')';
card_suits = ('HDSC')';
deck_nums = repmat(card_nums,4,1);
deck_suits = repmat(card_suits,13,1);
cell_nums = cellstr(deck_nums).';     %// Change strings to cell arrays...
cell_suits = cellstr(deck_suits).';   %// so we can use them in struct

%// Construct a struct array with fields 'value' and 'suit'
unshuffled_deck = struct('value',cell_nums,'suit',cell_suits);
disp('unshuffled deck:');
disp([unshuffled_deck.value;unshuffled_deck.suit]);

%// Shuffle the deck using the number of elements in the structure array
shuffled_deck = unshuffled_deck(randperm(numel(unshuffled_deck)));
disp('shuffled deck:');
disp([shuffled_deck.value; shuffled_deck.suit]);
```

Here's a test run:

```
unshuffled deck:
A23456789TJQKA23456789TJQKA23456789TJQKA23456789TJQK
HDSCHDSCHDSCHDSCHDSCHDSCHDSCHDSCHDSCHDSCHDSCHDSCHDSC
shuffled deck:
4976TT93KTJQJATK953A75QA82Q6226K5J784J4A3372486K859Q
CHSSSHCDSCSSHDDCDSHHCDHSDDCDHCCHHCHHHDDCSCDSSCHDSCSD
```

To access an individual card, you can do:

```
>> shuffled_deck(2)
ans =

  scalar structure containing the fields:

    value = 9
    suit = H
```

Or you can access the individual fields:

```
>> shuffled_deck(2).value
ans = 9
>> shuffled_deck(2).suit
ans = H
```

Unfortunately, I don't know of any way to simply index the struct array and get, for instance, `9H` as you would in a regular array using `disp(shuffled_deck(2,:))`. In this case, the only option I know of is to explicitly concatenate each field:

```
disp([shuffled_deck(2).value,shuffled_deck(2).suit]);
```

Comment: @CSE1010_Student Glad I could help. :)

Comment: Frankly I think for the general case of reshuffling a set of objects, you're better off creating a 1-dim vector of the objects, then doing a permutation of the numbers `1:numobjects` and assigning  `object_vec = object_vec(permuted_sequence)`

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Isn't that what I did?

Comment: Yes, with the exception that you used `size(data,1)` whereas I would prefer that `data` be a vector of "things" and `numel(data)` would be safer.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Yes, without resorting to a `struct` array, you need to specify (explicitly or implicitly) the dimension that gives you the number of "things". `length(data)` would be a way to specify the dimension implicitly, as it takes the dimension with the largest number of elements, but its use can lead to unanticipated results as an array grows in dimensions.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I've added a solution using a structure array that I think does what you suggest.